# Use posts_where to exclude posts ids from wp_query

Tags: posts, wp-query, exclude, posts-where

I want to use `posts_where` to exclude an array of posts ids from all queries in my site.

The array containing the posts ids depends on the user that is logged in.

Can someone please tell me how to use the filter `posts_where` to exclude a list of posts ids from all queries in my site?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you searched the site for `posts_where`? I get 376 results. Do none of those get you started?

Comment: I did search here, but none of the answers I found satisfied my request. However, I just found the solution in another site, I will post it shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `posts_where` it is a better idea to use `pre_get_posts` filter. Here is the code I end up implementing:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_unwanted_posts_filter' );
function hide_unwanted_posts_filter( $query ) {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    $key = 'unwanted_posts';
    $unwanted_posts = get_user_meta($user_id,$key,true);
    if(is_user_logged_in() && !empty($unwanted_posts) && !$query->is_admin) {
        $query->set('post__not_in', $unwanted_posts ); // id of page or post 21753
    }
    return $query;
}
```

If someone reads this and still wants to use the `posts_where` filter. Here is the same code (simplified) using this other filter:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where','hide_unwanted_posts_filter', 1, 2 );
function hide_unwanted_posts_filter($where, $wp_query = NULL) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wp_posts = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
    if ( !$wp_query ) {
        global $wp_query;
    }
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !$wp_query->is_admin) {
        $where .= " AND $wp_posts.ID NOT IN (22, 3)";
    }

    return $where;
}
```